# How to format special characters inserted into a Jinja2 template?

Tags: python, jinja2

I want to insert a bullet into an HTML file generated by a Jinja2 template. The Python code sends the string

```
'&#9679;'
```

but when in the HTML code it's generated as

```
&amp;#9679;
```

so the reader sees the code for the special character, no the special character itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to use the `safe` filter to prevent Jinja from [auto-escaping](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#html-escaping).